# How to create my own login page instead of simplesamlphp IDP login page

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I am using SimpleSamlePhp for IDP. Currently when i login it defaults to SimpleSamle login page. But i want to create my own customised login page. Can somebody please help me out with the steps how to achive this.

Answer (score 5):

The best starting point would be using the "Theming the user interface in SimpleSAMLphp" (https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/development/simplesamlphp-theming)

I just went through the motion of doing exactly that. You basically create a new module inside of SimpleSamlPHP and in there create a theme based on the default login page(loginuserpass.php), header and footer. Change the config file to use the new theme and it should then give you an isolated theme that you can "break". The loginuserpass.php file is the one providing the actual login screen/form itself whereas the header provides the typical HTML header information as well as the checking if the current session is already authenticated.